# ERC721 NFT minting to accept custom ERC20 token as payment

Tags: erc-20, nft, erc-721, mint, payments

When creating the contract for **minting NFTs** using the `erc-721` standard, I want to be able to accept payment from my own `erc-20` token instead of 'ETH'.

> How can this be accomplished?

Comment: This is implemented fully in this demonstration at https://github.com/fulldecent/spend-ERC20-create-ERC721 permissively licensed

Answer (score 11):

You can edit the `mint` function require the user to transfer certain ERC-20 tokens in your mint function. You can define a price for the ERC-721 tokens in terms of the ERC-20 token, and perform a `transferFrom` on the ERC-20 contract.

Of course, the user should have to approve the ERC-721 contract as a spender. The code could look something like this.

```js
contract MyNFT is ERC721 {
    address tokenAddress;
    uint256 price;

    constructor(address _tokenAddress, uint256 _price) ERC721("MyNFT", "NFT") {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
        price = _price;
    }

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        ERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), price);
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add to the accepted answer that the approve function has to be called from outside the contract (from the frontend for example). It took my a couple of days to figure this out, so just adding it in case someone is also struggling with it.

Comment: can u share that code?